# what command does elementary os use to maximize windows in hot corners?

Tags: settings, pantheon-terminal, command-line, hot-corners, gnome-terminal

What is the terminal command elementary os uses to maximize minimized windows?

I know the parameters are to only maximize the active window if it is minimized and if it is maximized minimize it.

so far i've figured out how to maximize the active windows by using the following:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

however, this does not minimize the window if it is maximized.

Im looking to replicate it elsewhere.

Thanks.